# Currying a generic method / function without loosing generic parameters

Tags: scala, generics, function-pointers

I just realized that my generic method:

```
def method[A](list: List[A]): A = { ... }
```

will result in a non-generic function type

```
val methodFun = method _
-> methodFun : (scala.List[Nothing]) => Nothing
```

when *currying* it, instead of keeping its generic type. Is there a possibility to keep the generic type information? I found out that I can define some explicit type as for example `String` by setting

```
val methodFun = method[String] _
-> methodFun : (scala.List[String]) => String
```

but this is not really what I want. I currently tend to use raw types to avoid this problems (as soon as I find out how) or is there a better solution?

Thanks for help!

PS: For why I want to do it:

```
def method1[A](list: List[A]): A = { ... }
def method2[A](element: A): Int = { ... }
// This will not cause a compiler error as stated before
// but this will result in (List[Nothing]) => Int
// but I want a (List[A]) => Int
val composedFun = method1 _ andThen method2
// The next line is possible
// but it gives me a (List[String]) => Int
val composedFunNonGeneric = method1[String] _ andThen method2[String]
```

Comment: It does not make sense as written, but in general, it can make sense. Either because there is more than one parameter or because I want to compose functions.

Comment: Ignore my first comment: That's not currying, it's eta-expansion. ;)  And I see the sense of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at your example:

```
def method1[A](list: List[A]): A = { ... }
def method2[A](element: A): String = { ... }
// The next line will cause a compiler error
val composed = method1 _ andThen method2
```

First, that doesn't give me a compiler error, but rather has the too-specific type `(List[Nothing]=>String)` that you mentioned.

If you want to understand why this doesn't work, think about it this way: what is the type you're expecting for `composed`? I think you want something like this `List[A]=>String`. However, `composed` is a `val`, not a `def` (i.e. it's an *instance* of a *function object*, not a *method*). Object instances must have specific types. If you wanted to use a generic type here, then you'd have to wrap this `val` in a class definition with a generic type, but even then the generic type would be restricted to the type specified/inferred for each specific instance of that class.

In short, if you want to compose methods and keep the type parameter, you need to compose them manually and declare it with `def` instead:

```
def composed[A](list: List[A]): String = method2(method1(list))
```